# How to sort post category using its Description

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, sort

I Am trying to sort my custom post categories according to its description. I tried below `args` but it did not work

```
$taxonomies = array(
    'post_tag',
    'product-type',
);

// Add the slugs of product types that should appear on the page
$slugs = array(
    'hand-tools',
    'mechanical-tools',
    'abrasive-wheel',
    'garden-tools',
    'screens',
    'locks'
);

$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'description',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty'        => false,
    'exclude'           => array(),
    'exclude_tree'      => array(),
    'include'           => array(),
    'number'            => $number,
    'fields'            => 'all',
    'slug'              => $slugs,
    'parent'            => 0,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'childless'         => false,
    'get'               => '',
    'name__like'        => '',
    'description__like' => '',
    'pad_counts'        => false,
    'offset'            => $offset,
    'search'            => '',
    'cache_domain'      => 'core'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom order fields I suppose as well.

```
 $categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'description',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ) );
```